# MATLAB image processing - How can I find the building footprint from an aerial image

Tags: image, matlab, image-segmentation

I got this aerial image of a warehouse from Google Map, and I'd like to analyze the characteristics of the building inside the image. How can I find the approximate building footprint?

I learned some functions for matlab image processing. But I'm still a newbie for image processing. I'll be very appreciated if anyone can help me.

Or is it easier to figure out the area using the roadmap image below?

[image: Satellite image]

[image: Road map image]

Comment: Well, your question does not have only one answer and it's a bit difficult to get a straight answer. You could train a system that identifies buildings in general and use computer vision and AI techniques or you can approach a solution using only image processing. To study the characteristics of a building in an image you firstly have to find where the building is. After that you do whatever you like. So, you should start studding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the roadmap image in Matlab, convert in in an 8bit greyscale image and use the following binarization.

```
BW = imbinarize(I,'adaptive','Sensitivity',0.68);
figure, imshow(BW,[0,1])
```

[image: Binarized image]

From Here you can either use `regionprops` ([link](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html?searchHighlight=regionprops&s_tid=doc_srchtitle)) or extract lines using a [Hough transform](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/hough.html?searchHighlight=hough&s_tid=doc_srchtitle).

Comment: @MichaelZang Processing the image you reduce the amount of non-useful information and you can use simpler tools to extract details you are interested in. I cannot go more in detail as the purpose of this site is not writing code for other people, but this information should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Great appreciation!